# Experience Optimisation trigger types

Tags: experience-optimization

When I add a promotion I can see the following triggers:

[image]

But in our trigger-types.xml file there are only the following nine triggers defined:

[image]

Where are all the extra triggers coming from and can they be removed?

- Current Date
- Navigation steps
- Number of results
- Page template

Conversely these are in my Xml but not explicity displayed in the drop-down:

- SmartTarget Page (Page template?)
- SmartTarget Region (Query type?)
- SmartTarget Active Period (Result type?)
- SmartTarget Publication (????)

**UPDATE**

The [docs](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-F167829F-C22A-4208-A8B1-7486325B0FF2&addHistory=true&query=default%2520triggers&scope=&tid=1191a661-97cd-46d6-87c9-5121bd6232ec&filename=GUID-F167829F-C22A-4208-A8B1-7486325B0FF2.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-F167829F-C22A-4208-A8B1-7486325B0FF2&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Ddefault%2520triggers&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1519141477263&currentQuery=default%2520triggers&currentScope=) describe 3 of the first 4 as Default Triggers - it's not stated explicitly but, as Velu mentions, can default triggers not be removed?

**Navigation steps** isn't in the docs though - is this connected to Fredhoppers Navigation settings?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first four are added by Fredhopper, the other four by XO. 
The former cannot be hidden and the latter are always hidden (as they are defined on the other tabs instead).

Actually, you could probably filter out the ones you don't want in a data extender, but I doubt it would be worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I believe trigger-type xml cached, do the following steps to clear the cache

1. Reload the Fredhopper Triggers http://localhost:8180/fredhopper/sysadmin/reload-config.jsp?select=trigger-types (This will clear the cache)
2. Follow this step to push this new trigger-type.xml to change to reflect in Live query instance

a.  Open this URL http://localhost:8180/fredhopper/admin/ and then go to File the configuration by clicking File in Business Manager, and then File again. This will open the Publication Manager.

b.  Publish the configuration by clicking Approve, and finally, click Publish

c.  Push the data to live (this will establish a permanent connection between the indexer and the live site, allowing for publishes in the future to be pushed to the live side) by running the command below: 
bin/fresh-index-to-live

3. Recycle the SDL Tridion Apppool in IIS.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Velu - I've changed my screenshot as it was from the wrong instance!

Comment: I believe that's default triggers always will be displayed